# How you can Trim Paths or Splines in Blender, like you can in After Effects?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I am working on a scene, where I will have lots of paths / splines going into a central object. I want to animate them in "trimming". In After Effects, you can easily add Trim Path modifier.

How you can do this in Blender easily for an entire Collection, for example?

Is there a specific Animation Nodes set up I could use? I know there is [Trim Spline node](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/spline/trim_spline/), but how can I point it to look for all the Splines inside specific Collection?

I would prefer to trim all of the Splines inside Collection randomly e.g. offset by 1-5 frames, than try to animate them one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

The 20 is the frame offset (i took a bit longer so you can "see" it better)

Result:

[image]

blend file:

[image]

and here the "variant" with random offset:

[image]

Comment: this is amazing. I will give it a go later on this week, when I set up the scene I want to animate. This is perfect! Thanks you.

Comment: You are welcome